# Cannot install xdebug

Tags: apache-2.2, php, zend-framework, xdebug

I'm getting a large number of undefined references when using

```
$ld xdebug.so
```

I have added the "zend_extension="/bla/xdebug.so"" to the conf for apache and it is giving me a config test failed because it cannot find the file. The file has been chown'd to www-data, so I do not believe it is a permissions error. I have run the wizard at xdebug.org/wizard.php to make sure the version would be correct, I updated to the version it recommended with an install from source and still receive the same error with apache and same output from $ld. I originally installed xdebug with:

```
$apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

And have also tried with:

```
$pecl install xdebug
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a combination of forgetfulness, stupidity and some actual errors. When I originally installed it the zend_extension was set in the php.ino. After this didn't work I tried in in the apache configuration (which is not where this goes). After the correct version was installed the extension enabler was still in apache rather than php.